# How can I tell `ConcurrentDictionary.GetOrAdd` to not add a value?

Tags: c#, concurrentdictionary

I have several cases where I use `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>` for caching of values, but often times I need to perform validation of the value to decide whether to add it to the cache using `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>.GetOrAdd(TKey, Func<TKey, TValue>)`.

Typically along the lines of:

```
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, ISomeObject> someObjectCache = 
    new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, ISomeObject>();
public ISomeObject CreateSomeObject(Type someType)
{
    return someObjectCache.GetOrAdd(someType, type =>
    {
        if(!Attribute.IsDefined(someType, typeof(SomeAttribute))
            // Do something here to avoid the instance from being added to
            //    `someObjectCache`

        ISomeObject someObject;
        // Typical factory functionality goes here
        return someObject;
    });
}
```

The way I handle this today is to throw an exception which appears to work fine, but I'd like a cleaner approach (maybe a flag I can set or a specific value I can set the return value to) to cancel the `GetOrAdd` from within the lambda (though it could realistically be replaced by a full blown method).

Based on my experience with other LINQ like methods, returning `null` will result in the value getting added without being checked as such (and reading the IL for `GetOrAdd` it looks like it'll result in the same problem), so I don't think that'll work.

Is there some way I can avoid using exceptions to cancel the add using `GetOrAdd`?

Answer (score 11):

From what I've read, there's [no guarantee that the Add factory method will only be called a single time amongst all callers to Get for the same key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997369.aspx).

The relevant portion from that page is at the bottom, quoted here:

> Also, although all methods of ConcurrentDictionary(Of TKey, TValue)
>   are thread-safe, not all methods are atomic, specifically GetOrAdd and
>   AddOrUpdate. The user delegate that is passed to these methods is
>   invoked outside of the dictionary's internal lock. (This is done to
>   prevent unknown code from blocking all threads.) Therefore it is
>   possible for this sequence of events to occur:
>
> 1) threadA calls GetOrAdd, finds no item and creates a new item to Add
>   by invoking the valueFactory delegate.
>
> 2) threadB calls GetOrAdd concurrently, its valueFactory delegate is
>   invoked and it arrives at the internal lock before threadA, and so its
>   new key-value pair is added to the dictionary.
>
> 3) threadA's user delegate completes, and the thread arrives at the
>   lock, but now sees that the item exists already
>
> 4) threadA performs a "Get", and returns the data that was previously
>   added by threadB.
>
> Therefore, it is not guaranteed that the data that is returned by
>   GetOrAdd is the same data that was created by the thread's
>   valueFactory. A similar sequence of events can occur when AddOrUpdate
>   is called.

The way I read this is that even if you're calling some locking in your Add delegate, you're not guaranteed that the value returned from your add is the one which will actually be used.

So, you shouldn't need to add any further locking, and instead could probably use the following pattern:

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<Type, ISomeObject> someObjectCache = 
    new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, ISomeObject>();
public ISomeObject CreateSomeObject(Type someType)
{

    ISomeObject someObject; 
    if (someObjectCache.TryGet(someType, out someObject))
    {
       return someObject;
    }

    if (Attribute.IsDefined(someType, typeof(SomeAttribute)) 
    { 
        // init someObject here
        someObject = new SomeObject(); 

        return someObjectCache.GetOrAdd(someType, someObject); // If another thread got through here first, we'll return their object here. 
    }

    // fallback functionality goes here if it doesn't have your attribute. 
}
```

Yes, this will result in some potential for new objects to be created potentially multiple times, but callers will all receive the same result, even if multiple are called. Same as GetOrAdd does now.

Comment: It would (and _I have_) but once you clutter that with all of the necessary thread locking mechanisms, it becomes rather messy (not that mine doesn't require locking... just not to the same extent). I'm looking for a cleaner solution, not one that requires having to effectively roll my own version of `ConcurrentDictionary`.

Comment: Updated my answer - GetOrAdd doesn't lock on the Add portion, only on dealing with the internal array bits. So, as I see it you shouldn't need any locks here if your intention is to only add validation.

Comment: Yes, I've read that portion of the docs, but this is still not what I am looking for. If I wanted to write so much code then I'd handle the locking myself.

Comment: Updated my answer again - This should be all the code you need (no need for locks!), other than actually initialising the object, and whatever fallback method you need.

Comment: +1 for proposing a possible alternative, but it doesn't directly answer the question.

Comment: When initializing the object is resource and time intensive, this method might cause it to load multiple times, which is not desirable. Using a Lazy in the factory is a better method to prevent that by forcing a single thread to do the initialization, but then we come back to the original question. If in a certain condition in the loading code (hidden in the GetOrAdd / Lazy), you want to cancel to prevent adding a Lazy<null> for example, this doesn't help.

Answer (score 3):

> All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection

```
// the dictionary now stores functions
private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Func<ISomeObject>> someObjectCache =
  new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Func<ISomeObject>>();

public ISomeObject CreateSomeObject(Type someType) {
  return someObjectCache.GetOrAdd(someType, _ => {
    if(ShouldCache(someType)) {
      // caching should be used
      // return a function that returns a cached instance
      var someObject = Create(someType);
      return () => someObject; 
    }
    else {
      // no caching should be used
      // return a function that always creates a new instance
      return () => Create(someType); 
    }
  })(); // call the returned function
}

private bool ShouldCache(Type someType) {
  return Attribute.IsDefined(someType, typeof(SomeAttribute));
}

private ISomeObject Create(Type someType) {
  // typical factory functionality ...
}
```

Now the value stored in the dictionary is a *function*; when you don't want caching to occur, the function always creates a new instance; when you want caching to occur, the function returns a cached instance.

Comment: Are you sure this would work? All you've done here is to move out the check to a function and return an instance of the type anyway. Some more explanation is probably required.

Comment: Moving the check to a separate function has nothing to do with the heart of the question, it was just some common refactoring....